# How can I prevent a JDialog from displaying when it is empty?

Tags: java, jdialog

I have a JDialog and it should not be displayed if it is empty. This is my code:

```
MyGridFaultDialog addFaultdialog =
    new MyGridFaultDialog(this.parent.getScene(),myFrame, user, this.getLayer());

// The following line creates a very small JDialog which is dragable.
// However, it should not be displayed if it is blank.
MyApp.showCenteredWindow(addFaultdialog, true);
```

I assume that I have to implement a simple `if` condition to make sure that an empty dialog is not displayed, but I don't know how to do that. How does the condition have to look like?

Comment: What does it mean for a JDialog to be "empty" ???  Furhermore, if you don't want to see it, why construct it in the first place ?

Comment: What is your definition of an _empty dialog_? Check the dialog state against that definition in your if-condition and you are done. No one here can tell what `MyGridFaultDialog` or `MyApp` is and how they behave, so no one can help you without any further information.